# How are mastery points earned?

Tags: league-of-legends

How are mastery points earned in League of Legends?

I'm just starting out and not quite sure. Here is what I'm talking about in-case you're unclear:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

New accounts start at Summoner Level 1.  As you play games, you'll gain [experience](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_%28summoner%29), which in turn will help you gain levels over time.  The maximum level you can attain is Summoner Level 30.

Every level you gain gives you a single mastery point, so at level 30 you'll have 30 [mastery points](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mastery#Attainment).

Comment: Yup yup. It's a crappy mechanic that favors more experienced players, but thankfully you don't have to deal with that once you hit ranked play.

Comment: @Preston Actually it's a great mechanic that incentivizes playing for a while and actually get better while playing similarly new players, unlike similar games where you just start out and play anyone, possibly peeple playing for years, quickly getting discouraged and dropping the game.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you level up you gain another mastery and rune point. Highest level you may earn is level 30. Games earn experience towards your leveling. If you want to level up even faster I believe there might even be an XP Boost you might be able to purchase in the League store.